# Add all digits of a string in c++

Tags: string, sum, digits, digit

I am trying to add all the digits of a string in c++, but it cannot passes all test cases. My code is given below.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    long long int count=0;
    cin>>str;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        count+=(str[i]-'0');
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't know how to resolve this problem can anyone help me out???

Comment: can you give any sample input for which it doesnt work?

Comment: Check if the character str[i] is a digit before you add. That might be a problem if the string has both digits and alphabet characters. if(isdigit(str[i])){count+=(str[i]-'0');}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    long long int count=0;
    cin>>str;
    //ASCII value of digits 0-9 lie between 48 to 57
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>=48 && str[i]<=57)
            count = count + (int)str[i] - 48;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code shown works correctly for strings that contains only digits (like "123").

There are two more cases that may need to be handled - non-digits and non-ASCII digits (this is less likely for beginner assignment).

One way to handle non-digits is to convert them to zero using conditional operator (also known as "ternary operator")

```
count += isdigit(str[i]) ? (str[i]-'0') : 0;
```

For second case if your program must support all [Unicode numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode) like “¼” you would need to either find library that supports full Unicode tables or write special cases yourself. Note that you'd need result to be `float` as not all numerals represent whole numbers.